# Asking warning message after saving workbook in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
wb_write = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
first_sheet = wb_write.get_sheet_names()[0]
ws = wb_write.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)
#here row=1 ,column= 5
ws.cell(row=i, column=mt_mac_id_column).value = MT_MAC
wb_write.save(file_path)
```

After writing data into xlsx file and saved in the same workbook.

Opened manually xlsx file in windows Changes are reflected in xlsx file but while closing the xlsx file it is asking for confirmation like "do you want to save the changes you made to file"

Why it is asking for confirmation? How do I avoid this warning?

Comment: Do you have the xlsx file open in Excel while you're making changes via Python?

Comment: No file has not opened in Excel while making changes via Python

Comment: Can any one help regarding above query?

Comment: My guess is that XLSX files might have a journaling system or parity bit that keeps track of saving.

Comment: Thank you Alex. But how to avoid this warning?